# Editext has some strange color

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, styles

Hello I have some EditTexts in versions 19+ are shown fine but in versions 19 and lower I get this result. [editText image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGy9T.png)

This is my code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player_name_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/name_hint"
    android:contentDescription="@string/a11y_enter_player_name"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>
```

And this is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="DargetTheme" parent="AppTheme" />

<!-- Toolbar theme -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<!-- Settings activity theme. -->
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="DargetTheme" />
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Add this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

Comment: @SagarJogadia thanks a lot, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Bug of Android studio 2.2 preview which are solved in Android studio preview 4 and 5

I recommended you to update the gradle with new version

**Android studio 2.2 Preview 4 or 5**

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview4available

**or you use with Gradle 2.1.0**

> ```
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem!